# Oracle INSERT Statement, String Literal Preceded by "b"

Tags: sql, oracle

I use DBeaver as my window into my Oracle database.  One feature of DBeaver is that it allows me to export a resultset as a series of `INSERT` statements.  I found that when I export a resultset that has a string literal that's surrounded by curly braces (`{{}}`), the generate insert statement precedes the literal with a `b` character, as follows:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (
  CRTED_TIME,
  TEMPLATE_TAG
)
VALUES(
  sysdate,
  b'{{id_5659}}'
);
```

I saw a few responses on StackOverflow that suggest Perl or Python do something similar to indicate that it's "byte" related.  But nothing specific to Oracle, and I've never seen this notation before.

Can anyone explain what this is?

Comment: My guesses: ODBC literal/Oracle literal/DBeaver templating. Please provide TEMPLATE_TAG data type

Comment: `TEMPLATE_TAG` is an inline literal string produced by concatenating a `NUMBER(22,0)` and a literal. I'm building it from an existing ID, so the select looks something like `select '{{id_' || sometable.id || '}}' from sometable;`

Comment: Actually I was thinking about `CREATE TABLE MYTABLE` statement but it looks like it is VARCHAR2

Comment: To be fair I am not able to run this code [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f3cdd6245f6b1ebe50cc3831f503bfe) so probably it is tool specific. You could try to run this code from SQL Developer to confirm it

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, I think it might actually be a bug in DBeaver. I can't run the statement either (even in the tool that generated the statement). I don't see it in their defect list, but it probably should be.  Thanks for looking at my question!